# LINQ to SQL generated functions, how to write a generic function for insert, update and delete

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

This may be a problem regarding generics and/or reflection... but I guess someone more experienced than I can say.

So, I have a DataContext class which was generated by SQLMetal.exe.

In addition to generating all the entities from the database, it also gives me a partial function for the insertion, updating and deletion of each entity.

What I'm noticing is that these functions all end up looking largely the same. For example, the Insert checks that the primary key (int) is zero. If it is, it calls 'InsertOnSubmit' on the given table within the DataContext, then calls SubmitChanges.

So the variables are the primary key field and the type. Other than that, they're the same. Can this be made more generic, so that I can write just one insert, update and delete function?

Thanks.

**Edit**: When I talk about functions, I also mean methods. Do they not mean the same thing? Additionally, I want three separate generic functions. Insert, Update and Delete.

Comment: Please show the code of one of your functions you want to generalize.

Comment: and why would you want that? they are generated for you anyway? Do not forget they are partial classes so you can extend them, you will loose that if you go generic

Comment: Ah, that's interesting Pleun - I didn't think of that way. It just seems like a pain when I have six entities and all their Insert, Update and Delete functions look rather similar. You'd recommend just leaving it as it is?

Comment: Yes, I would not bother too much. They are generated, quite clean and you anyway do not really call them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood this entirely.  By function you mean Method? Perhaps you could create a Persist(..) method that determines if it's an insert or update based on the key value, but difficult to see how or indeed the value of not having a Delete(..) method.